# How to find the nearest geohash in mysql?

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, geohashing

Recently I'm using GeoHash to hash the paired geo-coordinates into a hash value and store it in MySQL. Now I want to find the nearest hash given the other hash. I noticed that MYSQL provide BTree structure to find a range of nearest hashes by using the command "like" in SQL query.

The problem is, how could I find the nearest one instead of giving a range since sometimes I don't know the range.

Could someone give me a hint?

Really appreciate it.

Comment: You'll want to use [MySQL Spatial Extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html) when dealing with GIS coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

[*QuadTile*](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QuadTiles) (or GeoHash?) reversibly turns latitude + longitude into a single number.  But to use it to "find nearest" gets complex and messy.  Read about Z-ordering.  As I understand it, you would need to run 4 queries with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`; `UNION` the results together; then check to see which are best.

But it gets tricky to know what to do if the attempt did not find enough items.

`SPATIAL` indexes provide a more straightforward way.

[*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) is a technique for efficiently "finding nearest" for large datasets.